# Dynamic Manifest File for "android_secret_code"

Tags: android, dynamic, manifest

I'm following http://android.amberfog.com/?p=422 to start an activity by a secret code using below code:

```
 <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE" />
 <data android:scheme="android_secret_code" android:host="4636" />
```

What I would like to do is to have an option in the application itself, where the user can change the secret code to something they wish.

So as a default, user presses *#*#4636#*#* to get into application, and when user changes to some other code, say 5555, for the next launch it uses 5555 to launch application.

Are there anyways to do this?

I first thought about getting this code from strings.xml, but then I realized that I can't change the resources in strings.xml in runtime.

I, then, thought about putting this value into sqllite database or to shared preference, but I am not sure if I can pull this value back to manifest.

Are there any good ideas to do this?

I could also not use secret_code, but when user calls certain number (say 33334) then the application launch. Then user can change this number in the application. If this is possible, I can cope with this way too.

I know the above is possible in Shady_SMS but not sure how this application handled this.

Comment: Have a fixed code that fires an activity than then asks for your modifiable code? I think what you want cant be done exactly like that.

BTW, anyone who has anycut can launch your app with no code as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working using `BroadcastReceiver` with `Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`. User saves the secret code of their wish to `sharedpreference`, and on `BroadcastReceiver` `onReceive()`, I get the value from `sharedpreference` and use it to launch application.